# How to get rid of double backslash in python windows file path string?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, path

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dictionary = {"058498":"table", "064165":"pen", "055123":"pencil"}
```

I iterate over it:

```
for item in my_dictionary:
    PDF = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\File_%s.pdf' %item
    doIt(PDF)

def doIt(PDF):
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload( open(PDF,"rb").read() )
```

But I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\File_055123.pdf'
```

It can't find my file. Why does it think there are double backslashes in file path?

Comment: There is just a single backslash. You're seeing the string representation. The file doesn't exist.

Comment: The double backslash is not wrong, python prints/represents it that to the user way. If `a = r'raw s\tring'` and `b = 'raw s\\tring'` (no 'r' and explicit double slash) then they are both represented as `'raw s\\tring'`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The double backslash is not wrong, python *represents* it way that to the user. In each double backslash `\\`, the first one *escapes* the second to imply an actual backslash. If `a = r'raw s\tring'` and `b = 'raw s\\tring'` (no 'r' and explicit double slash) then they are both represented as `'raw s\\tring'`.

```
>>> a = r'raw s\tring'
>>> b = 'raw s\\tring'
>>> a
'raw s\\tring'
>>> b
'raw s\\tring'
```

For clarification, when you *print* the string, you'd see it as it would get used, like in a path - with just one backslash:

```
>>> print(a)
raw s\tring
>>> print(b)
raw s\tring
```

And in this printed string case, the `\t` doesn't imply a *tab*, it's a backslash `\` followed by the letter 't'.

Otherwise, a string with no 'r' prefix and a single backslash would escape the character *after* it, making it evaluate the 't' following it == tab:

```
>>> t = 'not raw s\tring'  # here '\t' = tab
>>> t
'not raw s\tring'
>>> print(t)  # will print a tab (and no letter 't' in 's\tring')
not raw s       ring
```

So in the PDF path+name:

```
>>> item = 'xyz'
>>> PDF = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\File_%s.pdf' % item
>>> PDF         # the representation of the string, also in error messages
'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\File_xyz.pdf'
>>> print(PDF)  # "as used"
C:\Users\user\Desktop\File_xyz.pdf
```

More info about [*escape sequences* in the table here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). Also see [`__str__` vs `__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436721/1431750).

Comment: there's no `d`: `'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\File_055123.pdf'`

Comment: Probably been edited out now.

Comment: Sorry but this was not a helpful answer. So if double slashes are the case, then how does one fix it????

Comment: @DeeWBee added some clarification about escape sequences and str vs repr.

Comment: @DeeWBee: You don't. There is nothing to fix. It's already fine.

Comment: Why is everyone hardcoding their paths?

Answer (score 12):

Double backslashes are due to `r`, raw string:

```
r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\File_%s.pdf' ,
```

It is used because the `\` might escape some of the characters.

```
>>> strs = "c:\desktop\notebook"

>>> print strs                #here print thinks that \n in \notebook is the newline char
c:\desktop
otebook

>>> strs = r"c:\desktop\notebook"  #using r'' escapes the \
>>> print strs

c:\desktop\notebook

>>> print repr(strs)   #actual content of strs
'c:\\desktop\\notebook'
```

Comment: In above example, if you display `strs` like `>>> strs` you should get `c:\\desktop\\notebook`. print doesnt show the escaped i.e. double slash \\

Answer (score 4):

save yourself from getting a headache you can use other slashes as well. 
if you know what I saying. the opposite looking slashes.

you're using now
**`PDF = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\File_%s.pdf' %item`**

try to use 
**

> **PDF = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/File_%s.pdf' %item**

**
it won't be treated as a escaping character .

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. Double backslash is just the way of the computer of saying backslash. Yes, I know this sounds weird, but think of it this way - in order to represent special characters, backslash was chosen as an escaping character (e.g. \n means newline, and not the backslash character followed by the n character). But what happens if you actually want to print (or use) a backslash (possibly followed by more characters), but you don't want the computer to treat it as an escaping character? In that case we escape the backslash itself, meaning we use a double backslash so the computer will understand it's a single backslash.

It's done automatically in your case because of the `r` you added before the string.

Answer (score -1):

alwbtc @
I dare say: "I found the bug..."

replace

```
PDF = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\File_%s.pdf' %item
doIt(PDF)`
```

with

```
for item in my_dictionary:
    PDF = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\File_%s.pdf' % mydictionary[item]
    doIt(PDF)`
```

in fact you were really looking for File_pencil.pdf (not File_055123.pdf).
You were sliding the index dictionary not its contents.
This forum topic maybe a side-effect.