# Python Conversion from WAV to FLAC

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wav, pydub, flac

Ive tried to run the following Code:

```
import sys
import os
import pydub
import glob

from pydub import AudioSegment

wav_files = glob.glob("X:\general\XXXXX\GSTT\Flac Dateien/*.wav")
#print(flac_files) 


for wav_file in wav_files:
    flac_file = os.path.splitext(wav_file)[0] + ".flac" 

    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(wav_file, format = "wav") 
    sound.export(flac_file, format = "flac")
```

but I Always get the following Error Message:

> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The System cannot find the file specified'

Comment: Is it just a typo? `glob.glob("X:\general\XXXXX\GSTT\Flac Dateien\*.wav")`?  Note you have a forward slash instead of backslash.

Comment: No, otherwise the print command wouldn't work, but it does.

Comment: Does [this question help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924706/how-to-get-rid-of-double-backslash-in-python-windows-file-path-string)?