# Adding a backslash in a string appends one more in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

Below is my code in ipython where I am adding a string value named "search_pattern" with a backslash to a dictionary. But when I print that dictionary back, it is replacing backslash with 2 backslashes.  How can I add "search_pattern" to the dictionary as the original string.

```
In [91]: search_pattern = '"code":2[,}]|"vnew":"2/|"url":"(/o|/\.[^/]|/r=[^/])*/2[/"?]'

In [92]: test = {
    ...: "test" : search_pattern
    ...: }

In [93]: test
Out[93]: {'test': '"code":2[,}]|"vnew":"2/|"url":"(/o|/\\.[^/]|/r=[^/])*/2[/"?]'}

In [94]: print(test)
{'test': '"code":2[,}]|"vnew":"2/|"url":"(/o|/\\.[^/]|/r=[^/])*/2[/"?]'}

In [95]: type(test)
Out[95]: dict
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of double backslash in python windows file path string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924706/how-to-get-rid-of-double-backslash-in-python-windows-file-path-string)

Comment: Be sure to read the accepted answer in the link not just the title, the answer explains exactly whats happening in your code. Also have a look at your output of the string when you do `print(test["test"])` you will see that extra backslash isnt there really.

Comment: My scenario is, I am directly inserting this into a column in  DB as json string. I can see that in DB, it is inserted with 2 slashes. I am using Python Django

Comment: How are you serialising the data into the db? how are you forming the json?

Comment: I am forming the json same like I mentioned in the question and just pass it to a django table object.

Comment: actually wait, json would also want the double backslash since backslash has special meaning in json. So i would expect it to keep the double backslash. If you put your json string from the db in a json validtor online it will say its valid, if you remove the extra double slash it will give you a parsing error.

Comment: But the problem here is even though I am having only one backslash while pushing to DB, python is appending 1 more. And while retrieving from DB, I am getting 2 backslashes.

Comment: yes but when you convert it back from json string to python object that will again be stripped out. have a look at https://repl.it/repls/FloweryQuestionableUnderstanding