# import sys showing paths with double backslash

Tags: python, import, environment-variables, sys

I am using Spyder when I import the environmental variables using:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I get the following:

```
['C:\\Users\\james', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3', '', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\james\\.ipython']
```

I am wondering why I get double backslashes, while the tutorial I am watching displays the paths with a single forward slash. eg

```
['C:/Users/james', ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924706/how-to-get-rid-of-double-backslash-in-python-windows-file-path-string).

Comment: when you use `print(list)` then it `repr()` to display elements on list to show all important information - like \\ - useful for debuging. If you print every item separatelly then it will print single \ - `for item in sys.path: print(item)`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that your tutorial is on not-windows system, and directories are like `this/is/path`. On Windows, the directories are like `this\is\path`. But in Python and in most programming languages, `\`(backslash) is used for escapes, so to write`this\is\path` you need to write 2 slashes.