# Python script crashes (due to double backslash?)

Tags: python

The topic on backslash in the path in Python in Windows has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924706/how-to-get-rid-of-double-backslash-in-python-windows-file-path-string), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice), but I none of the explanations seems to help me solve the following.

My script:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import sys
import os

root= tk.Tk() 
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Hello World already running!')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=label1)

root.mainloop()

sys.stdout.flush()
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

If I execute it from the CMD-console in the directory where the script is located like this:

```
py program4b.py
```

it works fine and everytime I close the 'Hello World' window it is opened again.

When I try to execute the script from any other location like this:

```
py "C:\Users\User1\Documents\Python Scripts\program4b.py"
```

the script is executed, but when I close the 'Hello World' window the script crashes with this message:

```
python: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\Python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change the folder name and not using any spaces
`"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Python_Scripts\program4b.py"`

see how it gets but in the python word
`python: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\Python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`