# how do I get all 3 to work I tried to use os.path.getsize, os.path.isfile, os.path.isdir but not working

Tags: operating-system

so I need to get the 3 commented codes to work but nothing I do seems to work any tips/tricks work be great thanks.

## This file prints information about a file

```
import os.path


def main():
    filename = "students.txt"
    abs_file_path = os.path.abspath(filename)  # returns absolute path for the given file
    dir_name = os.path.dirname(abs_file_path)  # returns filename without directory in front of it
    print()
    print()
    print("Absolute Path : ", abs_file_path)
    print("Directory : ", dir_name)  # returns directory given file is in
    print("Base Name : ", os.path.basename(abs_file_path))  # returns filename without directory in front of it

    #print("File Size : ", os.path.getsize(filename))  # returns the size of the given file in bytes
    # print("Is A File? : ", os.path.isfile(filename))  # returns 'True' if the given file exists
    # print("Is A Directory? : ", os.path.isdir(filename))  # returns 'True' if the given directory exists


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpidV.png)

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution to your question is to change the following line

```
  filename = "students.txt"
```

to

```
 filename = r"students.txt"
```

or

```
 filename = R"students.txt"
```

the r or R implies raw string read

Additionally, please read [solution detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924706/how-to-get-rid-of-double-backslash-in-python-windows-file-path-string).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I changed code I still got an error

Comment: it could be that the file "students.txt" does not exist in the path that you are running. Can you share the error message please.

Comment: I added an edit that shows an error