# How to keep encoded value from Python3 encode() method into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode

I have this code :

```
toto = 'récépissé.pdf'.encode('utf-8')

print(toto)
=> b'r\xc3\xa9c\xc3\xa9piss\xc3\xa9.pdf'
```

Of course it return a byte type, but I still want a string with the content of the encoded result.
I want a string like this :

```
'r\xc3\xa9c\xc3\xa9piss\xc3\xa9.pdf'
```

If I try to return a string by using a str() or decode(), it revert back to initial value.

PS: the final purpose is to pass string data in header for dropbox api.

Comment: Your desired result is `'rÃ©cÃ©pissÃ©.pdf'`. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
toto = 'récépissé.pdf'.encode('utf-8')

print(str(toto).split("'")[1])
```

Comment: I still got extra \ in the variable but not in the print output,
so it's seems ok for print but not for use.
`
>>> tutu = str(toto).split("'")[1]
>>> tutu
'r\\xc3\\xa9c\\xc3\\xa9piss\\xc3\\xa9.pdf'
>>> print(tutu)
r\xc3\xa9c\xc3\xa9piss\xc3\xa9.pdf
`

Comment: @NiBo What do you mean? That returns exactly what you are looking for

Comment: the print is really good but the variable is not ok

Comment: [How to get rid of double backslash in python windows file path string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924842/19392194)