# join aggregation with if condition on one column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| id | year | month | day | hour | timestamp | location_statindex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TP6045276120589011 | 2022 | 09 | 01 | 02 | 2022-09-01 02:01:23 | 1 |
| TP6031280073133032 | 2022 | 12 | 16 | 01 | 2022-12-16 01:48:42 | 1 |

with around 300.000 rows. 
With dytpes

```
id                             object
year                           object
month                          object
day                            object
hour                           object
timestamp                      datetime64[ns]
location_statindex             object
dtype: object
```

Now I create a new column which contains elements from each row, like:
`1\2022\09\01\02` 
with this code: 
`df['folder_path'] = df[['location_statindex', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']].agg('\\'.join, axis=1)`
**The question** is now if it is possible to change the aggregation, so that the value from location_statindex is a different string depending on an if condition. 
Like this:

```
location = '2'
if location in ['1','2','3','4']:
    location = f'Platz_optimiert_{location}'
elif location in ['5','6']:
    location = f'KSPlatz_{location}'
else:
    location = f'Platz_optimiert_TEF_{location}'
```

**Expected output** is a new column in the same dataframe with a joined string from the element of the corresponing row. For example the following string for the first row.
`'Platz_optimiert_1\2022\09\01\02'`

I already have a solution that uses the apply function from pandas with a self written function which contains the if block. But thinking about the size of the dataframe I want to try to reduce the necessary time. Is aggregation even faster than apply?

Comment: Please provide a properly structured expected output:

Comment: Isn't `df.year.dtype` of `int` type? `agg` should throw `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: Expected output is a new column in the same dataframe with a joined string from the element of the corresponing row. For example the following string for the first row. 'Platz_optimiert_1\2022\09\01\02'

Comment: The columns year, month, day, hour are all dtype of str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single assignment, by means of [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) routine.

Sample dataframe (note different `location_statindex` values for representative test):

```
In [473]: df
Out[473]: 
                    id  year month day hour             timestamp  \
0  TP6045276120589011   2022     9   1    2  2022-09-01 02:01:23    
1  TP6031280073133032   2022    12  16    1  2022-12-16 01:48:42    
2  TP6031280073133032   2022    12  16    1  2022-12-16 01:48:42    

  location_statindex  
0                  1  
1                  5  
2                  7
```

Assign `folder_path` columns with concatenated values:

```
loc_stat = df.location_statindex
df['folder_path'] = np.where(loc_stat.isin(['1','2','3','4']), 
                             'Platz_optimiert_' + loc_stat, 
                             np.where(loc_stat.isin(['5', '6']), 'KSPlatz_' + loc_stat, 'Platz_optimiert_TEF_' + loc_stat)) \
                    + '\\' + df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']].agg('\\'.join, axis=1)
```

---

```
In [488]: df
Out[488]: 
                    id  year month day hour             timestamp  \
0  TP6045276120589011   2022     9   1    2  2022-09-01 02:01:23    
1  TP6031280073133032   2022    12  16    1  2022-12-16 01:48:42    
2  TP6031280073133032   2022    12  16    1  2022-12-16 01:48:42    

  location_statindex                         folder_path  
0                  1        Platz_optimiert_1\2022\9\1\2  
1                  5              KSPlatz_5\2022\12\16\1  
2                  7  Platz_optimiert_TEF_7\2022\12\16\1
```

Comment: Great this works now. But: When i look at the element in the df it's with a singular backslash, but getting the element as a string it has double backslash. `KSPlatz_5\\2022\\09\\07\\12`. Do you know a way to prevent this, so i can use the element to do a listdir()?

Comment: @Anjo, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924842/3185459