# Problem opening image file using PIL.Image on Windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, image, runtime-error

I'm trying to open images using `PIL.Image`, but encountering this error:

```
Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir(".")
['Characters', 'Creatures', 'processing.ipynb']
>>> picpath = os.path.join("Characters", "4sprite", "Female_Archer", "Archer_Base", "Sprite_1.png")
>>> os.path.exists(picpath)
True
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open(picpath)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3305, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'Characters\\4sprite\\Female_Archer\\Archer_Base\\Sprite_1.png'
```

My best guess right now is that it has something to do with the way `PIL` is handling paths on Windows, because `os.path.exists` finds the file (and I've manually verified the file exists and can be opened and viewed). I notice the path has double backslashes, but the [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924706/how-to-get-rid-of-double-backslash-in-python-windows-file-path-string) I've found say that's the canonical representation. I saw someone encountering a [similar problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/rv2hl4/cant_get_rid_of_double_backslashes_in_filepaths/), but unfortunately their solution was to use `PIL.Image.open` (which is what's throwing the error for me).

Has anyone else encountered and worked around this?

---

Q: What type of image (encoding, channel count and size) is Sprite_1.png? Is it actually a PNG with a valid format? Can you show us the first hundred bytes? – Brian61354270

A:

```
with open(os.path.join("Characters", "4sprite", "Female_Archer", "Archer_Base", "Sprite_1.png"), "rb") as f:
     first_100 = f.read(100)
print(first_100)
```

gives `b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xa0\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00G'\xe9\xd3\x00\x00a.zTXtRaw profile type exif\x00\x00x\xda\xac\xbdY\x92\xc48\xb6m\xf7\xcfQ\xbc!\x10=8\x1c\x00$\xcc4\x03\r_k\xc1#\xab\xea\xdew%3\xc9"`

Comment: What type of image (encoding, channel count and size) is `Sprite_1.png`? Is it _actually_ a PNG with a valid format? Can you show us the first hundred bytes?

Comment: @Brian61354270
```with open(os.path.join("Characters", "4sprite", "Female_Archer", "Archer_Base", "Sprite_1.png"), "rb") as f:
    first_100 = f.read(100)
print(first_100)```
gives
`b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x0f\xa0\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00G'\xe9\xd3\x00\x00a.zTXtRaw profile type exif\x00\x00x\xda\xac\xbdY\x92\xc48\xb6m\xf7\xcfQ\xbc!\x10=8\x1c\x00$\xcc4\x03\r_k\xc1#\xab\xea\xdew%3\xc9"`

Comment: I recommend adding that to the question with an [edit]. But at a glance that looks OK. Header looks right for a 3840x4000 RGBA image with 8-bits per channel.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a couple of possibilities:

- PIL can't understand the path to the file, or
- PIL can understand the path to the file but cannot understand its contents.

Sharing the file, using something like Dropbox/Github/Google Drive or other service which doesn't change files would help here.

To check the first possibility, you can read the file yourself and pass that to PIL so PIL doesn't have to deal with your path. That would go like this:

```
# Slurp entire file
with open(os.path.join("Characters", "4sprite", "Female_Archer", "Archer_Base", "Sprite_1.png"), "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()

from io import BytesIO

# Wrap bytes in a BytesIO and pass to PIL
im = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
```

If that works, it means PIL can understand the file contents but cannot access them via your path. If it doesn't work, there's an issue with your file contents and you'd need to share it.

---

Another, maybe easier, way to test if the path is the issue is to simply move your image to the directory in which your program is running.

And a way to test if the image content is the problem, as opposed to the path, is to place a simple 2x2 pixel black PNG image at the original path in place of your *"unhappy"* image.